# How do I access the project map from a leiningen plugin?

Tags: clojure, leiningen

Let's say I create a new leiningen project and edit the project.clj file so it looks something like the following.

```
(defproject foobar "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"
  :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.5.1"]
                 ...
                 [clj-webmaster-tools "0.1.0"]]
  :plugins [[lein-ring "0.8.6"]
            [lein-webmaster-tools "0.1.0"]
  :webmaster {:sitemap "http://www.foobar.com/sitemap-index.xml" :robots "http://www.foobar.com/robots.txt"})
```

My question is, how do I access the :webmaster key in the project map for use in a leningen plugin I'm writing?

Comment: Access it where? During the build (if so, which phase)?

Comment: @noahlz No, for a leiningen plugin I'm writing.

Comment: It's passed in as a parameter to your plugin function, which you can access like any other map. See this example: https://github.com/noahlz/lein-hello/blob/master/src/leiningen/hello.clj

Comment: @noahlz Make than an answer so I can give proper credit.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you write a plugin, the first parameter passed to your plugin function is the project map.  It's a standard Clojure persistent map, so you can access it like any other map, i.e.

```
(defn my-plugin[project] 
  (println (:webmaster project)))
```